# Properties of Inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am unable to understand the following statements. If someone can explain with the help of numerical examples it would be great:

- If sides of an inequality are both positive or both negative, taking the reciprocal reverses the inequality
- If $0<x<1$ and $m$ and $n$ are integers with $m>n$, then $x^m<x^n<x$
- If $0<x<1$, then $\sqrt{x}>x$
- If $0<x<1$, then $\dfrac{1}{x}>x$ and $\dfrac{1}{x}>1$

Comment: Numeric examples are not proofs. Just plug in a couple of values. I left the original text when I transformed the image in text, but the first question should have "or" instead of the second "and" (in its present state it's meaningless).

Answer (score 3):

Below are some numerical examples of each of these inequalities.

1. You know that $2<4$. Now, $0.5=\dfrac{1}{2} > \dfrac{1}{4}=0.25$. 
   Similarly, $-2>-4$. now, $-0.5=\dfrac{-1}{2}<\dfrac{-1}{4}=0.25$.
2. Consider $a=4$ and $x=0.5$. Everything meets the stipulations. Then $xa=0.5(4)=2<4=a$.
3. Suppose $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $m=3$ and $n=2$. Then we have that $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3 = \dfrac{1}{8}$. Furthermore, $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \dfrac{1}{4}$. We know that $\dfrac{1}{8}<\dfrac{1}{4}$.
4. Suppose that $x=\dfrac{1}{4}$. Then we have that $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{4}}=\dfrac{1}{2}$. Furthermore, we know that $\dfrac{1}{2}>\dfrac{1}{4}$.
5. Suppose that $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$. Then we know that $\dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=2$. Furthermore, $2>\dfrac{1}{2}$. Also, $\dfrac{2}>1$.

Answer (score 3):

These statements can all be shown using basic rules of algebra.

The first statement *"If both sides of an inequality are both positive and both negative, taking the reciprocal reverses the inequality"*, can be easily understood by considering $a>b$ for some real-numbers $a$ and $b$. Clearly $\frac{1}{a}<\frac{1}{b}$ for the bigger the number the smaller it's reciprocal is. For instance if we take $a=2, b=1$, we have:

$$2>1 \text{ and } \frac{1}{2}<1$$

For the second statement, if we have $0<x<1$ then clearly multiplying a number by it will make it smaller because it is the same as dividing by some number greater than $1$. For instance, if we take $x=0.5=\frac{1}{2}$ then we have $ax=\frac{a}{2}<a$.

For the third statement we can remember that raising a base $b$ to a power $m$ can be viewed as multiplying $b$ by itself $m$ times, i.e.:

$$b^{m}=\underbrace{b\times \cdots \times b}_{m}$$

As we have $0<x<1$ multiplying $x$ by itself will give a smaller number still between $0$ and $1$. The more times we multiply itself by itself the smaller the result will be. For instance, if we take $x=0.5=\frac{1}{2}$ again and $n=2,m=3$ then we have:

$$x^n=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{4} \text{ and } x^{m}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}=\frac{1}{8}$$

And so clearly as $\frac{1}{8}<\frac{1}{4}<\frac{1}{2}$ we have $x^{m}<x^{n}<x$.

For your fourth statement, a nice way to view a square root for positive real numbers is bringing the number closer to $1$, so for some $x$ between $0$ and $1$ we have $\sqrt{x}>x$. This is obvious by squaring both sides to give $x>x^{2}$, which is clearly true as we showed in your third statement.

For your last statement it can be clearly seen to be true as dividing a number by some small $x$ is similar to asking how many times can $x$ fit into that number, therefore if $x$ is really small, it can clearly fit into $1$ many times. For a numerical example we can again take $x=\frac{1}{2}$, therefore we have $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}=2>1>x$.